# SPI Line Switching for Redundant Design

Tags: spi, multiplexer, transceiver

I am in the process of designing a full-duplex transceiver board.  I am using an ATmega328pb uC and a CC1125 radio.  This is for a CubeSat project, so in the interest of redundancy, I'm I would like to include 2 microcontrollers.  The ATmega328pb has two SPI outputs each so I had an idea where I implement muxes/demuxes to switch SPI lines connecting uC to radio from one uC to the other in the event of a failure.  Since there are 4 SPI lines, this design choice would require 8 2:1 muxes on an already small board.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any IC's that had this sort of functionality in one package, so that I didn't have to find room for 8 2:1 muxes on an already very small circuit board.  I am still a beginner in this area, so forgive any ignorance.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: These do exist. Have you searched for quad two to one analog mux chips? What did you find? If you have one radio chip and two MCUs, what is the purpose of eight 2:1 muxes?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I did look into them.  Sorry for the confusion, there are two radios and two MCUs.  Since the design is to be full-duplex have a radio for receiving and a radio for transmitting.  8 would be for the two radios.

Comment: Octal 2:1 muxes or bus switches still exist. What did you find so we don't repeat it here?

Comment: What will control the select to the multiplexers? What if that is incorrect?

Comment: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0007765693_1-2543006.pdf this is just one example of a 4-channel 2:1 mux I've found.  It's a mux/demux which is important because 1/4 of the SPI signals is in the other direction.  In terms of the select for the muxes,  I was considering just outputting a 1 from one of the GPIO pins to serve as the select.  That way, if something fails in the uC it flips low and the mux pulls the SPI lines from the other uC instead.